# Using EditorFor with DateTime in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using the `Html.EditorFor()` method for a `DateTime` field. But I have encountered with an error like *Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.*

Then I understood that it's because month value is greater than 12 or hour value is greater than 23. I'm selecting right values but I think because of localization issue, it changes the places between month and day.

And some code;

from view side;

```
 <tr>
    <td>
        <div class="editor-label" style="text-align: right;">
            <b>@Html.LabelFor(c => c.Created)</b>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(c=>c.Created)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.Created)
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

from view model side;

```
        [Display(Name = "Created", ResourceType = typeof(ModelLocalization))]
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
```

How can I format this? What should I do?

Comment: Please can you show us your code so far

Comment: I added some code; and there is a model bind code. It equals parsed time values to a var variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the TimePicker control of the (free) Telerik MVC extensions. [See here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/datepicker) for a demo and [here (for example) for download](http://nuget.org/packages/TelerikMvcExtensions).

Note: the MVC extensions were recently superseeded by a new product and maintenance of the MVC extensions will [stop soon](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/general/telerik-mvc-extensions-resources.aspx).